# Calling function from parent gives 'Uncaught TypeError: showSnack is not a function'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, parent-child, snackbar

Since Snackbars instant closes when navigating pages I had to put Snackbar in parent, but for some reason it doesn't work. Everything looks the same as the other posts. The error says that `showSnack` in Child isn't a function.

In Child we have a function in the prop that gets called with the button.

Simplified Child:

```
export default function Child({ showSnack }) {

    return (
        <Button variant="contained"
            onClick={() => {
                // navigate('/home');
                showSnack('Application submitted for review');
            }
            }>
            Confirm
        </Button>
    );
}
```

In Parent there is the actual function. The function is also passed into the Child as a prop of the same name.

Simplified App.js (Parent):

```
function App() {

  const [snackOpen, setOpenSnack] = React.useState(false);
  const [snackText, setSnackText] = React.useState('');

  function showSnack(snackText) {    
    setSnackText(snackText);
    setOpenSnack(true);
  }

  const handleCloseSnack = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === "clickaway") {
      return;
    }
    setOpenSnack(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/">
            <Route path="child" element={<Child showSnack={showSnack} />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>

      <Snackbar
        anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'bottom', horizontal: 'right' }}
        open={snackOpen}
        autoHideDuration={2000}
        // onClose={handleCloseSnack}
        message={snackText}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

EDIT (solution): I had to refresh the page